# JavaScript Clicked Button Color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my buttons to change to a certain color when one of them is clicked, and then they turn back to the default color when another one is clicked. The default color is gray, and then when a button is clicked, it stays orange until another button is clicked. I'm not really sure how to achieve that.

Using vanilla JS is a requirement for this so I can't use jQuery

Here is the HTML and JS:

```
<button type="button" id="button1">1</button>
    <button type="button" id="button2">2</button>
    <button type="button" id="button3">3</button>

...

var userRating

document.getElementById('button1').onclick = function () {
    console.log(this.id + " was clicked")
    userRating = 1;
}
document.getElementById('button2').onclick = function () {
    console.log(this.id + " was clicked")
    userRating = 2;
}
document.getElementById('button3').onclick = function () {
    console.log(this.id + " was clicked")
    userRating = 3;
}
```

Here is the CSS:

```
button {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #AAAAAA;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #AAAAAA;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #AAAAAA;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #AAAAAA), color-stop(1, #AAAAAA));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #AAAAAA 5%, #AAAAAA 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #AAAAAA 5%, #AAAAAA 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #AAAAAA 5%, #AAAAAA 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #AAAAAA 5%, #AAAAAA 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #AAAAAA 5%, #AAAAAA 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#AAAAAA', endColorstr='#AAAAAA',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#77b55a;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #4b8f29;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #5b8a3c;
}
button:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #FF851B), color-stop(1, #FF851B));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #FF851B 5%, #FF851B 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FF851B 5%, #FF851B 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #FF851B 5%, #FF851B 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #FF851B 5%, #FF851B 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #FF851B 5%, #FF851B 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FF851B', endColorstr='#FF851B',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#FF851B;
}
button:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

If you could point me in the right direction that would be great! I'm pretty new to this stuff.

Comment: You can use JQuery which will make it so much easier.

Comment: I can't use JQuery for this particular project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to add a CSS class for the selected button:

```
button:hover, button.selected {
  ...
}
```

And then, set the selected class for the button like this:

```
document.getElementById('button1').className = 'selected';
```

You can clear the selected class like this:

```
document.getElementById('button1').className = '';
```

Full solution is here: https://jsfiddle.net/3fzb1kk1/

Answer (score 2):

Try adding class and remove class.

You have to create a selected class with the color you want.

```
document.getElementById('button1').onclick = function () {
    this.addClass('class_selected');
    document.getElementById('button2').removeClass('selected');
    document.getElementById('button3').removeClass('selected');
}
document.getElementById('button2').onclick = function () {
    this.addClass('class_selected');
    document.getElementById('button1').removeClass('selected');
    document.getElementById('button3').removeClass('selected');
}
document.getElementById('button3').onclick = function () {
    this.addClass('class_selected');
    document.getElementById('button1').removeClass('selected');
    document.getElementById('button2').removeClass('selected');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/alanshearer/mLf1oL3u/).
That's your html:

```
<div class="buttons-container">
    <button type="button" id="button1">1</button>
    <button type="button" id="button2">2</button>
    <button type="button" id="button3">3</button>
</div>
```

you just need one method to manage click events like below:

```
$('.buttons-container button').click(function(){
    $('.buttons-container button.active').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

and use a css class:

```
.active{
  background-color:orange;
}
```

I hope it's enough for you!